# Crop to circle cell.imageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tableview, cell

Can't crop **cell.imageView?** to circle.

I was on many forums and nothing not found.

I use **tableView** with standard cell (non custom).

My code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "channelCell", for: indexPath) 
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.height / 2
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: channels[indexPath.row].userUrlImage))
    return cell
}
```

I get this image, check the image on the second user

[image]

**UPD.**

[image]

Comment: OK, what's the problem???

Comment: if you look more closely at the second user, you will see that the image is not round. it's more like an eye slit

Comment: use it and let me know the result : `cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.frame.size.height / 2`

Comment: did not help, updated the question

Comment: I guess I realized your problem. the second image height does not equal to it's width, check it and let me know

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: or you need photo size for second user?

Comment: put it before cornerRadius `cell.imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: cell.frame.size.height, height: cell.frame.size.height)`

Comment: if it works let me know to post an answer

Comment: not help me((((

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев try this  add `cell.imageView?.layoutIfNeeded()` and `cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true` and check what happens

Comment: first of all make sure your height & width constraints are same for that imageView, set aspect ratio constraint for the imageView.

Comment: The basic idea is to use `cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = min(cell.imageView!.frame.size.height, cell.imageView!.frame.size.width) / 2` but use guard let to unwrap the values

Answer (score 1):

you should set a frame for the Image view before :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "channelCell", for: indexPath) 
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.height, height: cell.frame.size.height)
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.height / 2
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: channels[indexPath.row].userUrlImage))
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time when you fill your cell, your cell didn't layout it frames.
1) The one approach is to call layoutIfNeeded() and then set corner radius, equal to cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView?.bounds.frame.height / 2
But it's not best from performance point of view, because you create redundant layout pass.
2) The another approach is to create the subclass of UITableViewCell and override it layoutSubviews. Then in layoutSubviews set corner radius.
3) The easiest and best from reusability point of view is to create subclass of UIImageView and override layout subviews.
Here is code for third approach

```
/*
Create custom UITableViewCell and use CircledImageView instead of UIImageView.
*/
class CircledImageView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height / 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the cell height are different, so you can set height by below code and get proper round image.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50    // set your cell height
}
```